# Connecting web Service with ajax connection string

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, connection

I'm tring to connect a web service which i m writing. But i keep taking following error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) " I couldnt figure out what should ı do?

here is my ajax code

```
var a = "a";
$.ajax({
type: "POST
url: "FethData.asmx/returnEmployeeInfo=?r" + Math.random(),
data:"{s: '" + a + "'}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
cache: false,
success: function (response) {
var result = response.d;
if (result == "OK") {
alert('asd');
 }
},
timeout: function (response) {
alert("timeout");
},
error: function (msg) {
alert("error");
}
})
```

and my web service

```
public class FetchData : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[WebMethod]
public string returnEmployeeInfo(string s)
{
string a = "a";

return "OK";
}


}
```

Comment: `url: "FethData.asmx/returnEmployeeInfo=?r" + Math.random()`, try `url: "FethData.asmx/returnEmployeeInfo"`
Also, couldn't you use JSON.stringify on a real object, like:

`data: JSON.stringify({'s': 'a'}),`

Comment: i tried exactyly what u say but still taking same error. Do i need to configure webconfig file